# How do I load columns from different tables into a cursor and display them?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display all of the rows in GAMETABLEs, and also display one of the rows in HOWTOPLAY.  I have googled around but cannot figure out how to load columns from 2 tables into one cursor and display them.

Using oracle 11g.

This is my stored procedure code:

```
  PROCEDURE GetLotteryGame (lg_id IN number, lg_ref OUT lotg_ref_cursor) IS
   BEGIN
   OPEN lg_ref FOR
    SELECT a.GAMEDETAILSID,a.GAMENAME,a.GAMECOST,a.GAMEDESCRIPTION,a.WHERETOPLAY,b.HOWTOPLAYINFO
      FROM GAMEDETAILS a 
        INNER JOIN HOWTOPLAY b
          on b.GAMEDETAILSID = a.GAMEDETAILSID
     WHERE a.GAMEDETAILSID >= lg_id;
END GetLotteryGame;
```

This is my call procedure code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON size 100000

DECLARE 
v_cursor             LOTTERYGAMEPKG.lotg_ref_cursor;
v_gamedetailsid      GAMEDETAILS.gamedetailsID%type;
v_gamename           GAMEDETAILS.gamename%type;
v_gamecost           GAMEDETAILS.gamecost%type;
v_gamedescription    GAMEDETAILS.gamedescription%type;
v_wheretoplay        GAMEDETAILS.wheretoplay%type;
v_howtoplayinfo      HOWTOPLAY.howtoplayinfo%type;
BEGIN
LOTTERYGAMEPKG.GetLotteryGame(lg_id => 1,
                          lg_ref => v_cursor);

LOOP
  FETCH v_cursor
  INTO v_gamedetailsID, v_gamename, v_gamecost, v_gamedescription, v_wheretoplay,         v_howtoplayinfo;
EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_gamedetailsID || ',' || v_gamename || ',' || v_gamecost || ',' || v_gamedescription || ',' || v_wheretoplay || ',' v_howtoplayinfo);
END LOOP;
CLOSE v_cursor;
END;
```

Error Report:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 17, column 143:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "V_HOWTOPLAYINFO" when expecting one of the following:

) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec as between from using || member submultiset
The symbol "," was substituted for "V_HOWTOPLAYINFO" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get?  What line is the error on?  Or what behavior do you see that isn't what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a concat operator between `',' v_howtoplayinfo)`.

Should be `',' || v_howtoplayinfo)`.

By the way, you are allowed to break such long lines. If you do, you can read them without having to scroll to the right, and you are more likely to spot such errors yourself.